# write SUP class objects into file

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, file, sup

Is there any way to write SUP(Sybase Unwired Platform) classes objects into text file in iOS, like we can write NSString or NSNumber objects. Some examples of writing SUP classess objects into text file is needed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is a "SUP class"?

Comment: SUP is sybase unwired platform

Answer (score 0):

In version SUP2.1.3, you can use tostring method of the generated class to get a string representation of the attributes of the class.